# RewriteCond all domains white www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

if i have a domain www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com on same folder, how can i get the the www.(domain.com) go to domain.com?

hob sombardy can help me :)

my ownd idé is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i don't know about it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: perfekt :) tanks for the fast helping.